# Adding an Items into Listview

Tags: c#

I have completely split the string in text file that is delimited by a comma.
My problem is that I cannot show the data on my list view.

I have use this code, but when I run it and debug, there is value inside the variables. but then I finished the debugging, No Items were added in the Listview.

```
    private void ColumnHeaders()
    {
        lvResult.View = View.Details;
        lvResult.Columns.Add("ファイル名");
        lvResult.Columns.Add("フォルダ");
        lvResult.Columns.Add("比較結果");
        lvResult.Columns.Add("左日付");
        lvResult.Columns.Add("右日付");
        lvResult.Columns.Add("拡張子");

       for (int i = 0; i <= lvResult.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            lvResult.Columns[i].Width = lvResult.Width / 6;
        }

    }


private  void viewTextFile()
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtResultPath.Text + "A.YMD6063_new.txt");

    for (int x = 0 ; x <= lines.Length; x++)
    {
        string[] col = lines[x].Split(new char[] { ',' });
        ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem();
        for (int i = 0; i <= col.Length; i++)
        {
            lvItem.Text = col[i].ToString();
            if (i == 0)
            {
                lvResult.Items.Add(lvItem);
            }
            else
            {
                lvResult.Items[x].SubItems[i].Text = lvItem.Text;
            }    
        }   
    }
}
```

[image: Properties Listview]

Comment: What is the view property of your `listview`

Comment: What do you mean by Properties sir? It has a detailed view.

Comment: i have attached the image of the properties of my Listview Sir.

Comment: Does it have any columns?

Comment: The columns were added programatically sir.

Comment: Make sure the 'View' property of the list view is set to 'Details'. Also, add enough columns to the list view.

Comment: @Nishil. I already did sir. but no items were added in the Listview

Comment: Could you post the code on how you add columns?

Comment: @AlainElemia. I did sir. see the edits

Comment: @AlexisVillar is this your exact code? your posted `for loop` will have an out of range exception.

Comment: Yes Sir. That is my exact Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a sample code I tried. Hope this would help you.

```
        listView1.Columns.Add("column1");
        listView1.Columns.Add("column2");
        listView1.Columns.Add("column3");
        listView1.Columns.Add("column4");

        string[] lines = new string[] { "value01,value02,value03,value04", "value11,value12,value13,value14" };

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {                   
            listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(line.Split(',')));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the ListView.View to Details. This can either be achieved in the Designer or programatically like this:

   `lvResult.View = View.Details;`
2. Add each line of your file:

   ```
   private void viewTextFile()
   {
       foreach(var line in File.ReadAllLines(somefilepath))
           AddLineToListView(line);
   }

   private void AddLineToListView(string line)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
           return;

       var lvItem = new ListViewItem(line.Split(','));
       lvResult.Items.Add(lvItem);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks :) But i have the result at the answered by @nishil :)